# Webpage showing this webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: php

Whenever I open this page it is showing this webpage has a redirect loop. Could someone please suggest me what is wrong with the code??

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['views']);
    $i = $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['views'] = $i;
    echo "Session Value is ".$_SESSION['views'];
    $tbl_name = "mgen_validation_check";
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("mgen") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE md5values='$i'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 0) {
        header("location:popup.php");
    }
    else {
        header("location:login.php?id=".$_SESSION['views']);

        //Unset the variables stored in session
        unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
        unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
        $_SESSION['code'] = "mgen";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: What is the name of the file we're looking at? Is it `popup.php` or `login.php`?

Comment: Also stop using mysql, and start using msqli or PPDO..

Comment: Do you have redirection rules on your .htaccess?

Comment: Dieter is drunk. He meant MySQLi or PDO. 
Alternatively, you could use a handy ORM like Propel, Doctine, or IDIORM -